# How to prove that this algebraic field extension is not separable therefore Galois.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, extension-field, elliptic-curves

Edit: Assume field K has a positive characteristic.

Let's say I have an algebraic function field $F$ over field $K$ with characteristic > 0 given by a Weirstrass equation $w(x,y)=y^2-x^3-ax-b \in K[x,y]$ in other words $F$ is the fraction field of the quotient ring $K[x,y]/(w)$.
$w$ is irreducible. And lets assume that $w$ is smooth.

Now let's denote $t=y+\lambda x + \mu \in K[x,y]$. Assume that the "curve" (line) given by $V_t$ intersects $V_w$ at exactly 2 different places. Therefore I know that the polynomial $w(x,-\lambda x - \mu)$ has only 2 distinct roots, therefore it is not separable because its degree is 3.

I want to show that $F/K(t)$ is not a Galois extension. My guess would be to try to find an element of $F$ such that  $w(x,-\lambda x - \mu)$ is a minimal polynomial of that element over $K(t)$. Since I know it is not separable the extension would not be separable.

I also see that $w(x,-\lambda x - \mu)=-y^2+x^2\lambda^2 + 2\lambda \mu x + \mu^2 \in F$ since $y^2 = x^3+ax+b$ in $F$.

Is it the right way? Or should I look for something else then separability. I have spent hours trying to find something but no luck.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think it's not Galois?

Comment: @BrandonCarter it is an exercise, so i assume it is true.

Comment: what makes you think it's not separable ?

Comment: @mercio djao has given me a counter example for characteristic 0. So if I assume the characteristic is > 0, then is it still not? This was given to me as an exercise so I'd think its true. From the context of other exercises I shouldve assumed p>0.

Answer (score 1):

What is the full, complete, unabridged statement of the exercise? The question as posed is false. Consider $K=\mathbb{C}, a=-1, b=0, \lambda=0, \mu=-\sqrt{2/(3 \sqrt{3})}$. Then $w(x,y) = y^2 - (x^3-x)$ and $t(x,y) = y-\sqrt{2/(3\sqrt{3})}$ intersect in exactly two points: $(2/\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{2/(3 \sqrt{3}))}$ and $(-1/\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{2/(3 \sqrt{3}))}$. However, $F/K(t)$ must be separable, because $K(t)$ has characteristic zero, and every field extension is separable in characteristic zero.

Comment: thank you for the counter example. The question was posed like this but I guess I'd assume now that K is of characteristic > 0 since it is not true in 0. Any ideas on that?

Comment: The same counterexample is also a counterexample with (say) $K=\mathbb{F}_{37}$, since in characteristic $p$ every inseparable extension must have degree at least $p$, and $F/K(t)$ has degree much less than $p=37$. In this case $\mu = 19$, and the points in $V_t \cap V_w$ are $(10,19)$ and $(32,19)$. (Note, in the course of working out the $p=37$ case I noticed a bug in the original example. The bug is now fixed.)

Comment: thank you again. i guess you forgot minus before 19 because μ should be −19 since 0=y+μ⟹y=19 but the points still stands. I just realized that I should prove then that $F/K(t)$ is not Galois. so I have that it is finite and simple and separable, so the only thing that remains is normality? So is it not normal?